# Может ли СУБД быть источником события для внешней программы?

Tags: mysql, postgresql

При работе с БД обычно источником события является клиентское приложение.
Например - клиент подключился и вставил запись в БД. СУБД ответило ошибкой или приняло данные.

Но возможен ли в какой СУБД обратный сценарий - отправка клиентскому ПО уведомления, что БД что-то произошло?

Да, например в Mysql(MariaDB) есть механизм планировщика событий - но там тоже работа идёт внутри БД.

Известные мне решения: клиент просто бесконечно опрашивает некую таблицу с определённым интервалом и, при появлении в ней данных что-то делает.

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/57061

Comment: MySQL не имеет встроенных средств для решения такой задачи. Ищите UDF, которая выполняет какие-то внешние вызовы/программы/прочее...

Answer (score 1):

Для postgres есть несколько вариантов.

### NOTIFY/LISTEN.

Из плюсов - работает из коробки.
Минусы:

- негарантированная доставка уведомлений
- необходимость вручную создавать триггеры

[Тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25218653/2231972) можно посмотреть рабочий пример на python.

### Логическая репликация

Это гораздо более надежный [способ](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/logical-replication.html). В этом способе [лог транзакций](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/wal-intro.html) декодируется и используется приложением. Доставка гарантированна, т.к. потребитель уведомляет сервер после получения и обработки сообщения.

Сначала нужно запустить postgres с включенной логической репликацией и с установленным [плагином](https://github.com/eulerto/wal2json) для декодирования WAL в json. Я использую готовый [образ](https://hub.docker.com/r/debezium/postgres) cо сконфигурированным postgres и установленным wal2json для простоты:

```
docker run -d --name "logical" -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=123 -p 10000:5432 -d debezium/postgres:14
```

Пример кода, который слушает изменения:

```
import psycopg2
from psycopg2.errors import UndefinedObject
from psycopg2.extras import LogicalReplicationConnection

my_connection = psycopg2.connect(
    "dbname='postgres' host='localhost' port='10000' user='postgres' password='123'",
    connection_factory=LogicalReplicationConnection,
)
cur = my_connection.cursor()
try:
    cur.drop_replication_slot("wal2json_test_slot")
except UndefinedObject:
    pass
cur.create_replication_slot("wal2json_test_slot", output_plugin="wal2json")
cur.start_replication(
    slot_name="wal2json_test_slot", options={"pretty-print": 1}, decode=True
)


def consume(msg):
    print(msg.payload)
    msg.cursor.send_feedback(flush_lsn=msg.data_start)


cur.consume_stream(consume)
```

Теперь если выполнить операцию типа `insert into table1 values (1, 'hello')` получим:

```
{
    "change": [
        {
            "kind": "insert",
            "schema": "public",
            "table": "table1",
            "columnnames": ["i", "t"],
            "columntypes": ["integer", "text"],
            "columnvalues": [1, "hello"]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL может генерировать уведомления [Notify](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgresql/14/sql-notify), отправляя их всем подписанным на канал [Listen](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgresql/14/sql-listen).

Comment: Может быть важно, что notify/listen не гарантируют доставку.

Comment: Возлагать на СУБД эту задачу вообще решение сомнительное. Это задача должна решатся на доменном уровне с применением приёмов реализации сквозной функциональности и отказоустойчивых очередей. https://www.rabbitmq.com/